# How to fix xsd schema validation errors? (rephrased)

Tags: xml, xsd

Having made a mess of my previous question, here is a fresh attempt.

I am trying to write a XSD schema based on an example from MSDN. I have modified the example so that the XSD is local to the xml file and does not use a namespace. However, the XML fails to validate.

XSD file (leda_sys_params.xsd):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/po.xsd" 
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/po.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
   Purchase order schema for Example.com.
   Copyright 2000 Example.com. All rights reserved.
  </xs:documentation>
 </xs:annotation>

 <xs:element name="purchaseOrder" type="PurchaseOrderType"/>

 <xs:element name="comment" type="xs:string"/>

 <xs:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="shipTo" type="USAddress"/>
   <xs:element name="billTo" type="USAddress"/>
   <xs:element ref="comment" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="items"  type="Items"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="orderDate" type="xs:date"/>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="USAddress">
      <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
       Purchase order schema for Example.Microsoft.com.
       Copyright 2001 Example.Microsoft.com. All rights reserved.
      </xs:documentation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        Application info.
      </xs:appinfo>
     </xs:annotation>

  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="name"   type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="city"   type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="state"  type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="zip"    type="xs:decimal"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="country" type="xs:NMTOKEN"
     fixed="US"/>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="Items">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="productName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="quantity">
       <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
         <xs:maxExclusive value="100"/>
        </xs:restriction>
       </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="USPrice"    type="xs:decimal"/>
      <xs:element ref="comment"   minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="shipDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"/>
     </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="partNum" type="SKU" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <!-- Stock Keeping Unit, a code for identifying products -->
 <xs:simpleType name="SKU">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="\d{3}-[A-Z]{2}"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

XML file (leda_sys_params.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<purchaseOrder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="leda_sys_params.xsd" orderDate="1999-10-20">
    <shipTo country="US">
        <name>Alice Smith</name>
        <street>123 Maple Street</street>
        <city>Mill Valley</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>90952</zip>
    </shipTo>
    <billTo country="US">
        <name>Robert Smith</name>
        <street>8 Oak Avenue</street>
        <city>Old Town</city>
        <state>PA</state>
        <zip>95819</zip>
    </billTo>
    <comment>Hurry, my lawn is going wild!</comment>
    <items>
        <item partNum="872-AA">
            <productName>Lawnmower</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
            <comment>Confirm this is electric</comment>
        </item>
        <item partNum="926-AA">
            <productName>Baby Monitor</productName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
            <shipDate>1999-05-21</shipDate>
        </item>
    </items>
</purchaseOrder>
```

The XML fails to validate:

```
3 145: Error schema document 'leda_sys_params.xsd' has different target namespace from the one specified in instance document ''
3 145: Error no declaration found for element 'purchaseOrder'
3 145: Error attribute 'orderDate' is not declared for element 'purchaseOrder'
```

All errors are on line 3.

Please can you help me fix the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declared the elements to be in a targetNamespace (with the attached URL `http://tempuri.org/po.xsd`), you need to have an XML instance with element in the same namespace.

Thus your sample XML should be:

```
<purchaseOrder xmlns="http://tempuri.org/po.xsd" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="leda_sys_params.xsd" 
   orderDate="1999-10-20">
```

---

Alternate solution: if you don' need the namespaces at all, then leave your XML as-is, and modify your schema as follows:

```
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
       elementFormDefault="unqualified">
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it would be simpler to remove the target namespace, so that there is no dependency on a website. How would I do that please?

Comment: Thanks, I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: One more question: why does the above example use 'xs:' rather than 'xsd:', which I have seen elsewhere?

Comment: There's no difference, since you're using the right url (`http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`). Remember that with namespaces, it's the associated URL that matters.